# Get Logged user name

Tags: access

I am using MS Access 2013 Web app with SharePoint lists.
I want to get user name of SharePoint logged user to retrieve the user's items in Access form.
I tried select current_user(); but it is always give me back an administrator!!

How to get current user name from MS Access form??